# Error al acceder a un objeto dentro de un objeto: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, javascript-objeto

Estoy con un proyecto de React y tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar ciertos datos. Tengo un documento dinámico json en MONGODB con el siguiente formato.

A la hora de mostrar todo el grupo de publicaciones, no hay problemas, para ello, he usado **useState([])** y se muestran todo el grupo de publicaciones con sus respectivos datos.

Pero a la hora de mostrar una sola publicación de forma individual usando **useState({})**, el valor de **post.title** se muestra pero el de **post.char.char1** o **post.group1.img1** me aparece un error en consola *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'img1')*.

¿Alguna de ayuda para poder resolver este problema? Gracias de antemano!

```json
[
    {
        "type": "1",
        "title": "Lorem",
        "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit,",
        "group1": {
            "img1": "/assets/lorem1.jpg",
            "img2": "/assets/loremvilla.jpg",
            "img3": "/assets/lorem.jpg"
        },
        "char": {
            "char1": "lorem",
            "char2": "lorem",
            "char3": "lorem"
        },
        "gallery": {
            "img1": "/assets/lorem1.jpg",
            "img2": "/assets/lorem1.jpg"
        }
    }
]
```

El set de post:

```
const EachPost = () => {   
  const { post_id } = useParams();   
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});    
  useEffect(() => {     
    const fetchPost = async () => {       
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/post/${post_id}');
      setProperty(response.data);     
    };     
    fetchPost();   
  });
```

El post contiene la info ya que el título `(<h2>{post.title}</h2>)` puedo mostrarlo sin problemas. Cuando obtengo el error es al acceder a los objetos.

Comment: Parece un problema de deep copy , muestra el código dónde haces el set de `post` con `useState`, también revisa la consola para confirmar antes y despues del set, que el estado `post` contiene toda la información.

Comment: `const EachPost = () => {
  const { post_id } = useParams();
  const [post, setPost] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPost = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(
        'http://localhost:5000/api/post/${post_id}'
      );
      setProperty(response.data);
    };
    fetchPost();
  });`

El **post** contiene la info ya que el título (<h2>{post.title}</h2>) puedo mostrarlo sin problemas. Cuando obtengo el error es al acceder a los objetos...

Comment: Bien, una ultima verificación, da un console.log a `response.data` antes del `setProperty(response.data);`, asegúrate de que venga toda la información ahi también, es antes del set.

Comment: Yo te diría que el problema lo busques en otro lado. En el render de los objetos utiliza el [encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) así: `{post.char?.char1}` y `{post.group1?.img1}`. Tampoco olvides agregar un [arreglo de dependencias](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) a tu _useEffect_: `useEffect(() => {...}, [post_id]);`

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider graciasss!! Tras añadir el encadenamiento opcional y el array de dependencias al useEffect se renderiza todo perfectamente! Muchas gracias a ti también @ g.4. Aprovecho para preguntaros... algún consejo para filtrar los post por 'type'??? Es decir, si es de tipo '1' mostrar los de ese tipo y si es de tipo '2' mostrarlos solo los de ese tipo... gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Ok entonces la colección es dinámica, un documento no siempre presentará la misma estructura. Agregue ese dato a la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Yo te diría que el problema lo busques en otro lado. En el render de los objetos utiliza el [encadenamiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) así:

```
{post.char?.char1}
```

y

```
 {post.group1?.img1}.
```

Tampoco olvides agregar un [arreglo de dependencias](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) a tu useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ...
}, [post_id]);
```